# Blogengine.net handler section not working with IIS8

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, blogengine.net, webresource.axd

Blogengine handler section is giving problem on production, on local it working.
When I removed handler section from web.config the site works but partially and distorted and all axd files not found.

Have another site with same config but on IIS7 is working properly.

Please help.